# Asp.Net Core : Get the list values ​of a table by string Id with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a color table that contains values, and I have a string of IDs that are the IDs of this table.I want to return only values ​​whose ID is in the string of IDs

Table Color:
[image]

string Ids :

`1,3,5`

I want to receive the values ​​whose IDs are 1, 3, and 5 as a list ?

Comment: you can use .contains() to search your list from the table..

Comment: @ZakarieAbdallah how?

Comment: You have two answers, both are incorrect, if you are using EF Core. Which ORM do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I use EF Core 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EF Core you have to use `Contains`:

```cs
var ids = stringIds.Split(',')
   .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
   .ToArray();

var colors = db.Colors
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, only if the IDs are strings, it can be converted to int object?

Comment: Yes, why not `var ids = stringIds.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();`

Comment: This code gives an error.this part `int.Parse(s)`

Comment: Update your original question with additional information about string ids and show sample. `int.Parse` will fail if string cannot be converted to integer.

Comment: I changed my question

Answer (score 1):

```cs
List<string> result = Datatable.Rows
   .Cast<DataRow>()
   .Where(x => listOfId.Contains((int)x["Id"])) //This part does the filtering of id
   .Select(x => x["Name"])
   .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
int[] ids = { 1, 3, 5 };
var colors = (from d in ids from c in Colors where d == c.Id select c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote `Linq` in the TAGs, I assume that you are using `EntityFrameworkCore` or `LINQ to SQL` or something similar. 
In this case, this example will help you:

```
int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3 };

var nameList = db.Colors
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();
```

where `db` is `DbContext`

Comment: Your query is wrong.You cannot use select after Where

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy Use Select after Where is allowed. My mistake was that I accidentally wrote Concat instead of Contains, and I've corrected it now